# ScrollViewer's Scrollable Height is not updated in store apps

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm having custom panel.Here ScrollableHeight is not updated based on the available size from MeasureOverride. I have found that by setting vertical offset like

ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticallOffset(VoffsetValue);

but it is not set. Since ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight is less than the Voffset value.

I have updated the content's Extent height inside the Measure override method after that have invoked InvalidateScrollInfo method to set vertical offset value.

Could you please anyone clarify the flow of ScrollableHeight and MeasureOverride available size?

Comment: Can you share any code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi @FilipSkakun,

I have added the child element for panel at runtime once content of scrollviewer is measured.

In button click, i have set the vertical offset value. but it is less than scrollable height. hence, i have used the below code re measure and update the scrollableheight value 

But it doesnt helps to resolve the ScrollableHeight issue in Scrollviewer.

Comment: **while(ScrollOwner.ScrollableHeight < VerticalOffset)
                        {
                            ScrollOwner.Measure(new Size(TotalExtent.Height, TotalExtent.Width));
                            ScrollOwner.UpdateLayout();
                            ScrollOwner.ScrollToVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset);
                            //verticalBar.Maximum = VerticalOffset;
                            //verticalBar.Value = VerticalOffset;
                        }**

Comment: I don't think that will work, although I'd have to see the whole code to say for sure. How about simply setting the size of whatever is hosted in the `ScrollViewer` to control the `ScrollableHeight`?